# NUnit test not working with Entity Framework ToListAsync()

Tags: entity-framework-6.1, nunit-2.6

The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. 
Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. 
For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

I am new to NUnit.
I have developed the Nunit test cases for` async queries.
But I am getting above error. I refereed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx link but not able 
to solve error.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

public interface IWork : IDisposable
    {
        IBlogRepository BlogRepository { get; }

```
    IDBContext Db { get; }
}

 public class BlogRepository : GenericRepository<Blog>, IBlogRepository
{

    internal ContainerRepository(IWork work)
        : base(work)
    {

    }
}
public interface IBlogRepository : IGenericRepository<Blog>
{

}
 [TestFixture] 
public class AsyncQueryTests 
{ 
    [Test] 
    public async Task GetAllBlogsAsync_orders_by_name() 
    { 
        using (var work = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IWork>())
        {
        var data = new List<Blog> 
        { 
            new Blog { Name = "BBB" }, 
            new Blog { Name = "ZZZ" }, 
            new Blog { Name = "AAA" }, 
        }.AsQueryable(); 

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>(); 
        mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<Blog>>() 
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator()) 
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<Blog>(data.GetEnumerator())); 

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>() 
            .Setup(m => m.Provider) 
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Blog>(data.Provider)); 

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression); 
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType); 
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator()); 

        var mockContext = new Mock<IWork>(); 
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.BlogRepository.GetQuery()).Returns(mockSet.Object); 
        ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<IWork>().Use(mockContext.Object));

            foreach (var blog in mockSet.Object)
                {
                    mockContext.Object.BlogRepository.Add(blog);

                }

        var service = new BlogController(); 
        var blogs = await service.GetAllBlogsAsync(); 

        Assert.AreEqual(3, blogs.Count);           
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Well, it works in the link you provided. You must have missed something. Impossible to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: @GertArnold I am getting error while adding this : null reference  mockContext.Object.BlogRepository.Add(blog);

Comment: And when I add anything in work it does gets available in the controller db context.

Comment: Now you completely changed the question. What happened to `ToListAsync()`? And this is not about NUnit, but about how to set up Moq. I've given up mocking `DbContext` long ago. It's a continuous fight against anomalies and differences between the real thing and LINQ-to-objects. Only integration test give firm results.

Comment: @GertArnold I got error for while working with Async EF and NUnit.As you said the link example works so I again tried to set up Mock as in the link. But that too not worked. I dont want to pass my context like in the example given. I am totally confused as where to start from.

Comment: I just want to fetch the data without passing my context object to async controller. And the controller is using EF ToListAsync.